# Make a header's edges line up with the page?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website and I made a header, but the header edge is not lining up with the edges of the page. I want to use CSS to fix the problem. Please help I have tried `margin: 0;` `top: 0;` `left: 0;` `right: 0;` also if you know how I can figure out how to make the "Games For You" in the header show on top of the left side of the div box (header). I can only make the text go to the left, not to the top. but I want there to be a little bit of space at the very top of the header (to look better).

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #060606;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Games For You</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Games For You</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Give the `html` and `body` tag `0px` for padding and margin. `padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;`

Comment: I actually figured out the first part I just need help with the second part.